# Взаимодействие с объектами. Приравнивание

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток.
Суть моей проблемы изложу простым примером.

```
class MyClass{
static int MyMethod(){
    int a;
    a=1;
    return(a);
}};

void main(){
int a;
a = MyClass::MyMethod();
}
```

На предпоследней строке будет ошибка "undefined reference to MyClass::MyMethod()"

Что я упускаю?

Comment: Этот код действительно [порождает массу ошибок](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sDy7ckcPODxOWGo9), но вот ничего похожего на "undefined reference" (это ошибка линкера когда чего-то не достает) тут быть не может, до стадии линковки этот код не дойдет. Приведите настоящий код и полный текст ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что вы упустили слово `public`. Ваша функция оказывается закрытой и недоступной для вызова.

Если сделать ее `public` - все нормально компилируется: https://ideone.com/7Ms3Cf

```
struct MyClass{
    static int MyMethod(){
        int a;
        a=1;
        return(a);
    }};

int main(){
    int a;
    a = MyClass::MyMethod();
}
```

Да, еще вы забыли, что `main` возвращает `int`.

Comment: в функции сразу возвращайте  единицу, а еще лучше просто хранить static const int a = 1;  и только (комментарий для автора  вопроса...)

Comment: Реализациям разрешено иметь дополнительные варианты `main`, в том числе с возможностью возвращать `void`. Понятно, что такой код не будет переносим.